# Stratified-K-fold in main code to be the same for learning_curve routine

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am writing a code in which in the body commands I use a stratifiedKfold for cross validation.
As it would be great to have some plot about the score hit on the training and on the validation set, I read about running the learning_curve routine to plot.
Then comes this weird thing (or I wish I'm simply wrong): in the options of the learning_curve routine, I can do a crossvalidation for a stratified-K-fold (specifying cv in the arguments, for instance), however that would be a **different, new** one with respect to the one that I define in the main code. 
I cannot find how to solve this: the idea is to have the plots for the same stratifiedKfold that I use in the main text.

----- In the main code -----

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(difficulty_list,10)

for train, test in skf:
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train],X[test], y[train], y[test]
```

then I would like to call the validation learning curve for this given folding, but I can only cast the following

```
 plotValidationCurve(regressor,X_train,y_train,item)
```

which uses a separate method, to draw the plots:

```
 def plotValidationCurve(estimator,X,y,item):
 ml_method_list = ['AdaBoost','LASSO','Elastic Net','SVR','Random Forest','Gradient Boosting','RGF']
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Training examples")
plt.ylabel("Score")
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(estimator, X, y, train_sizes=np.linspace(0.05, 1.0, 20),cv=10)
```

Where notice I specify here a 10-stratified-k-cross validation, but not the same I specified above in skf.

Is there a way to just do that?

Comment: Can you please include the relevant code in your post?

Comment: Sure, just did it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I solved it: what about passing skf as an argument of the routine for plotting the learning curve and setting in the arguments cv=skf ?

Something like

```
plotValidationCurve(regressor,X_train,y_train,item,skf)
```

and then

```
def plotValidationCurve(estimator,X,y,item):
...
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(estimator, X, y, train_sizes=np.linspace(0.05, 1.0, 20),cv=skf)
```